# Fill all requiered args with "None" if they are empty

Tags: python, function

The args I must assign are v0, v1 ... v18

```
sx.set_attribute(v5="test",**{f"v{i}": None for i in range(19) if not eval(f"v{i}") == ""}})
```

I'm getting the following error message:

`NameError: name 'v0' is not defined`

Comment: Your dict comprehension assumes that you have 19 variables `v0`, `v1`, etc defined. At least one (`v0`) is not.

Comment: You are also going to get an error if `v5` is not empty, as it will be passed as a keyword argument twice.

Comment: `eval(f"v{i})` expects there to be a variable named `v0` already defined. You probably shouldn't have *any* such variables in the first place; there should be a single dict or list `v` with the values you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wrapper function will remove additional keyword arguments:

```
import inspect


def set_kwargs_default_none(fn):
    fn_kwargs = [p.name for p in inspect.signature(fn).parameters.values() if p.kind >= inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD]

    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        tmp = {k: None for k in fn_kwargs}
        tmp.update(kwargs)
        return fn(*args, **tmp)

    return wrapped


@set_kwargs_default_none
def foo(v0, v1, v2, v3, *, v4=1):
    return (v0, v1, v2, v3)


test_args = {f"v{i}": i for i in range(3)}

foo(**test_args)
```

Result:

```
(0, 1, 2, None, None)
```

And without the wrapper:

```
TypeError: foo() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'v3' and 'v4'
```

Comment: yes. `def set_attribute(self, v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, etc..):
        self._name=v0  etc...`

Comment: @mathandlogic Sorry I misunderstood the question, one second

Comment: @mathandlogic When you do `@set_kwargs_default_none` dont put curly brackets at the end like `@set_kwargs_default_none()`

Comment: @mathandlogic If you dont know what a wrapper function is in python, I would start there, but I don't know of a good tutorial off the top of my head

Comment: thx again for your valuable time!